# How to use single quote inside an echo which is using single quote

Tags: php, echo, quotes

First of all, i have gone through the related questions.. haven't found any answer..
I m using this code to display a message

`echo 'Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi's ';`

How can i make this work, as any quote inside this echo will break the statement...

Comment: `echo 'Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi\'s ';`

Comment: +1 K102. You can read [that](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php) and, you want using doubleQuote in echo function : 

    echo " it's me!" ;

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Either escape the quote with a backslash, or use double quotes to designate the string.

```
echo 'Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi\'s';

echo "Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi's";
```

Answer (score 5):

Escape the quote using a backslash.

```
'hello\'s'
```

The single quote that appears after the backslash will appear on screen.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the function [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)?  It even uses your example.

I personally prefer the function [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) 
which does the same thing but has flags which let you specify its behavior.

like so:

> echo htmlspecialchars("O'Rielly", ENT_QUOTES);

This shows the string properly on an HTML webpage.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, the escape sequence character is the backslash (`\`). You can add this before special characters to ensure that those characters are displayed as literals. For example:

```
echo 'Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi\'s ';
```

Or you can also write like this:

```
echo "Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi's ";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo <<<EOT
You can put what ever you want here.. HTML, " ' ` anyting will go
Here goes your message with an apostrophe S like thi's
EOT;
```

Be sure to read [this](http://in.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) before using such kind of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since the methods from the answers didn't work for my situation I ended up just calling a new echo everytime the type of quote changed through the code and swapped the type of quote to start the echo, it's 2019 now and I don't know about any other solution since I am really new to programming but this worked fine for me, example:

```html
        else {
          echo '<a onclick="document.getElementById(';
          echo "'open_login').style.display='block'";
          echo '" class="branding w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile w3-light-blue w3-hover-white w3-right"href="#login"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login do Aluno</a>';
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be that you are passing the variable through HTML in single quotes ''. If it is the case, try using double quotes: "".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review existing answers to the questions. Try not to duplicate those, especially on questions that are 8 years old.