# MySQL Syntax Error trying to find empty column value

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm trying to pass check to see if a field is NULL or empty:

```
 $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $this->table . '` WHERE `wp_permalink` IS NOT NULL AND `wp_permalink` <> "" AND `id` != 2 AND `ga_page_views` != ' . $nogo . ' ORDER BY ga_page_views DESC LIMIT 6');
```

How can I fix the syntax error for `wp_permalink` <> ""? Thank you for your help. I am still learning.

Comment: Do you want to check if it's not null and not empty or if it's null or empty? From query it looks like it's one and from description the other one.

Comment: both.. not null and not empty

Comment: I would just use `LENGTH(wp_permalink) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the code like this.

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $this->table . '` WHERE `wp_permalink` IS NOT NULL AND `wp_permalink` <> \'\' AND `id` != 2 AND `ga_page_views` != ' . $nogo . ' ORDER BY ga_page_views DESC LIMIT 6');
```

Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes generally aren’t used in SQL, but that can vary from database to database.

check this link also
[difference between single and double quotes in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

[How to use single quote inside an echo which is using single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792990/how-to-use-single-quote-inside-an-echo-which-is-using-single-quote)

Answer (score 0):

String literals are denoted by single quotes:

```sql
wp_permalink IS NOT NULL and wp_permalink <> ''
-- Single quotes-----------------------------^^
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I use single quotes, which is why I resorted to double quotes